# Netbeans Platform access DTD from other module

Tags: xml, dtd, netbeans-platform, netbeans-7.1

We're writing a Netbeans platform app, and we want to add some data as an XML files.
Also we want to have a DTD for that files, and we want to put it in one of our main modules, as it should be used in different places and dependent XML files will be in a different modules. Now how can I point to that DTD from XMLs in another modules?

I'll be very thankful for any advice.

Also maybe mentioned above idea is bad but that's all I could think about, so critique is welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you have a module file structure like this

```
MyModule
  com.mydomain.mypackage
    layer.xml
    main.dtd
```

And `layer.xml` contains

```
<filesystem>
    <folder name="MyDTDs">
        <file name="myMainDTD" url="main.dtd"/>
    </folder> 
</filesystem>
```

Then you can get a `FileObject` to the dtd file from another module by doing

```
FileObject root = FileUtil.getConfigRoot();
FileObject myDTDs = root.getFileObject("MyDTDs");
if (myDTDs != null) {
    FileObject mainDTD = myDTDs.getFileObject("myMainDTD");
}
```

And from the `FileObject` you can get an `InputStream` and so forth.